# Chrome extension, javascript: Why is this firing twice?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a very very simple bit of code in my (test) Chrome extension:

```
    function test()
    {
    alert("In test!");
    }

   chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabid, changeinfo, tab) {
    var url = tab.url;
        if (url !== undefined) {

        test();
    }
   });
```

My question is, why is `test()` firing twice? And more importantly, how do I make it fire just once?

Comment: My guess is that the are really 2 tab updates occurring, causing the event handler to fire twice.

Comment: I have just that one piece of code... so where is the second one coming from?

Comment: see my answer for clarification on why your code *looks* like it will only call `test()` once, but in reality it could call `test()` any number of times.

Comment: Good catch, Rob. To be more precisely about the "any number of times" and to answer the question where the second call comes from: Every initial tab load *updates* the tab's state to 'loading' -> call #1. And when it's finished loading, it's state will be *updated* to 'complete' -> call #2. So, for each _page load_, the **tab object** gets updated twice.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Have a look at what the different states are when the event is dispatched. I presume, that it is getting dispatched once when the state is "loading" or when the state is "complete". If that is the case, then your problem would be fixed with:

```
 function test()
    {
    alert("In test!");
    }

   chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabid, changeinfo, tab) {
    var url = tab.url;
        if (url !== undefined && changeinfo.status == "complete") {

        test();
    }
   });
```

Comment: No, it did... just forgot to reload the extension :))   
Gotta wait 3 mins before i can accept your answer...  
Thanks

Comment: Sadly, I have the same issue as @Nikklas, and both times the status is 'complete'. Wtf chrome?

Comment: Oh, I'm glad I found this page. I was wondering why it fires twice.Now, it's clear!

Comment: FOR CLARIFICATION PURPOSES, it fires when there is any update and there are different kinds of updates. An update can be a URL change, favicon, status, etc. So you will need to look at the changeinfo object to see what kind of change it is. For me, I first checked if changeinfo says the update is a "status" change, then if tab status is "complete"
`if (changeinfo && changinfo.status && tab && tab.status == 'complete')`
I discovered this after printing all arguments to the console.

Answer (score 11):

I was also confused by this and tried to find the answer. Only after some experimentation did I figure out why I was receiving multiple "complete" update events for what I thought was a single page "update".

If your page has iframes, each will trigger a "complete" event and bubble up to the parent content script. So more complex pages will trigger a slew of onUpdated events if they have iframes.

Comment: Nope, no iframes in my page.

Comment: Yes, that was my case. It happened on the complex page, so I received at least 7 "complete" events, now I have to deal with this :)

Answer (score 2):

When you write the following code:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabid, changeinfo, tab) {
    var url = tab.url;
        if (url !== undefined) {

        test();
    }
});
```

You're calling `addListener` and telling it to call `test()` **not immediately** but rather **whenever the tab is updated**.  Tab update events are broadcast by the Chrome browser itself, which in turn, causes your `test()` code to run.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old but anyway... it's happening to me  too and maybe this can help someone. Looking into the Tab object that the handler function is receiving, I saw that the *favIconUrl* property is different in both calls so I guess it has something to do with that although I have no idea about the reason behind this.

I thought it was a bug but after a second thought and some testing I discard the bug theory.

What I know so far is that if two properties are changed, the event is triggered twice with the *changeInfo* object containing one property each time. In other words if for instance the properties that change are *status* and *favIconUrl*, then

```
changeInfo = {status:"complete"};
```

and then in the next call

```
changeInfo = {favIconuUrl : ".... whatever ..."};
```

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm not sure why our code is firing twice, I had a similar problem and this answer helped me out a lot.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49307437/15238857
Vaibhav's answer was really smart in incorporating validation in the form of the details object of the request.
When logging the details object I noticed a trend that the original firing had a frameId of 0, and the second firing was always something else. So instead of positively validating that you're in the correct submission of the URL, I like using an if statement to return and bail out when you have the duplicate entry.
I'm using onCompleted here, but it should work for onUpdated as well.

```
chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(details => {
    //need to make sure that this only triggers once per navigation
    console.log(details);
    if (details.frameId !== 0) return;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by checking the title of the tab when updated:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {

var title = changeInfo.title;
    if (title !== undefined) {
       doSomething();
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Twice is due to status being loading once and status being completed once.
if you are unconcerned about the status, you may also try the onCreated event. That will be fired just once!

Comment: As mentioned above, it can fire more than just once when status is "complete" (multiple completes). After printing the arguments, you can see it fires when the update is triggered by the favicon. So checking the `changeInfo` object to see if it is a "status" change, and then checking if the status of the tab is "complete" will make sure you only see it for the completion of the page load.

Comment: Now with `onCreated`, it doesn't fire at all!