# Chrome extension - "webNavigation.onComitted" event is fired twice

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a chrome extension now.

I came across this problem that "webNavigation.onComitted" event is fired twice on facebook.com when I access facebook.

This is the code I have now, but it prints "Facebook" twice in console.

```
// while logging in facebook.com, it prints "facebook" in console.
chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted.addListener(function(e) {

    console.log("Facebook");

}, {url: [{urlPrefix : 'https://www.facebook.com/'}]})
```

On the other hand, this code works ok. 
When I access youtube.com, it prints "youtube" just once  in console as I expect.

```
// on accessing youtube.com, it prints "youtube" in console.
chrome.webNavigation.onCommitted.addListener(function(e) {

    console.log("youtube");

}, {url: [{urlPrefix : 'http://www.youtube.com/'}]})
```

Anyway, I want it load only once when accessing facebook.com.
How can I make it work??

If anyone knows how to fix this problem,please help me out!!

Thanks in advance!!

**What I tried**

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation.html#events

I tried all other event types such as "onBeforeNavigate", "onCompleted".
But it doesn't solve my problem.

**Useful related post on stackoverflow**

[Chrome extension, javascript: Why is this firing twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168124/chrome-extension-javascript-why-is-this-firing-twice)

This page is similar to my problem but, this page is talking about "tabs.onUpdated" event.

since "tabs.onUpdated" event doesn't provide event filter, I prefer using "webNavigation" API.

Comment: Have you already checked whether Facebook contains a frame pointing to Facebook?

Comment: nope. I'll check it out right now! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation.html#event-onCommitted:

> frameId ( integer )
>
> 0 indicates the navigation happens in the tab content window; a positive value indicates navigation in a subframe. Frame IDs are unique within a tab.

If you add `console.log(e)` inside your event handler, you'll see that the first event has `frameId` = 0, while the second event has a positive number, which means it belongs to an iframe. If you are only interested in main window navigation, just add a check for `e.frameId === 0` at the beginning of your event handler.