# Messages aren't being received in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a Chrome extension to keep track of how long I spend on certain websites. I only want to count time in the active tab. As such I have an `onUpdate` event listener in my extension page, `background.js`

The `onUpdate` event fires multiple times when you load a page, but only one of these events is the changing of the url. You can see here for a further explanation of this: [Chrome extension, javascript: Why is this firing twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168124/chrome-extension-javascript-why-is-this-firing-twice), but this is not my question. Thus, only one of the `changeInfo` objects has the `url` property.

I want to grab the new URL from the `onUpdate` event and use it to determine which message to send to my content script. I can send a message to the content script in any situation it seems, but when I introduce a check after the `onUpdate` event to ensure I only fire when there is a URL property, the `onMessage` event in my content script stops firing. Here is the code:

#### background.js

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  if (changeInfo.url) {
    chrome.storage.sync.set({'on_site1': "true"}, function() {
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {"message": "moved_to_site1"}, function() {});
    });
  }
})
```

#### content.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({"message": "this is a response"});
    if (request.message === "tab_changed") {
      foo1();
    } else if (request.message === "moved_to_site1") {
      foo2();
    } else {
      foo3();
    }
  }
);
```

Under the above conditions the `onMessage` Event does NOT fire. The trick is in the `background.js`, here. When it changes to the following:

#### background.js

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  chrome.storage.sync.set({'on_site1': "true"}, function() {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {"message": "moved_to_site1"}, function() {});
  });
})
```

Now the `onMessage` event is fired in `content.js` and everything works, except this doesn't allow me to check the URL I changed to. I need to be able to check what the URL is before I send the message, and I can't figure out a workaround to this strange problem or even why it happens. Any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: The problem is that the URL is not set after you switch tabs, it's set only when the tab is loading. I think you should use chrome.tabs.onActivated and chrome.tabs.get inside (to get the url for the tabId).

Comment: The problem is that the content script (and message listener) is not yet loaded into the new page when the onUpdated event is fired. Enclosing the sendMessage in a setTimeout() to delay the event fixes it. Or you could wait until the changeInfo.status changes to 'complete'.

Comment: @kainC I figured out the changeInfo.status 'complete' thing, but the problem is that this is a separate firing of the onUpdated event. Thus, this event does not contain the url so it doesn't really solve the problem as I can send a message but then I can't send a message dependent on the url.

Comment: You can use the onChange.url event to set the url in storage, but the onChange status event to actually send it. Or if you use the delay, you can have it tied only to the onChange url event and assume the page will be loaded when the message sends (less robust)